# Eclipse for PHP IDE adds some "use const False\MyClass\true;" when organizing import

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

When using the shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+O** on my **Eclipse for PHP IDE** (Version: 2022-09 4.25.0), I have a `use` line which appears at the top of my class:

```
use const False\MyClass\true;
```

The logs show the error `Undefined constant 'False\MyClass\true'`

It only appears when using `true` boolean value in the class code.
Here is an example of code triggering the import use statement :

```
public function addBreadcrumb(string $label, string $route, array $parameters = [ ]) {
    $this->breadcrumb[] = [ 
        'label' => $label,
        'url' => AppContext::url($route, $parameters)
    ];
    $this->showBreadcrumb(true);
}

public function showBreadcrumb(bool $showBreadcrumb) {
    $this->showBreadcrumb = $showBreadcrumb;
}
```

Can someone help on this, please ?

Just googled the error but did not found anything.

Comment: Can you show how you have used `true` in your code, perhaps narrow it down to the one that is causing this to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. I was related to my IDE which was unable to perform Validation of the code at the launch of the workspace. Since I have fixed this Validation error, I was able to correctly load the workspace and the shortcut is now working perfectly. The Validation error occured because I was using 2 different autoloaders on my project : one from Composer (vendor) and the other one was a custom one for my internal librairies.